# Perl getting unique values from file column

Tags: arrays, perl, file, unique

i have a file that has the following data:

```
col1 col2 ext3 rw
col1 col2 ext3 rw 
col1 col2 ext3 rw 
col1 col2 nfs rw 
col1 col2 ext4 rw 
col1 col2 iso9660 ro
```

what am trying to do is to read the file and print unique values from column 3. The column 3 contains the ext3,ext4,nfs ...

currently my output is:

```
ext3 
ext3 
ext3 
nfs 
ext4 
iso9660
```

and my output should be :

```
ext3
nfs
ext4
iso9660
```

Below is what i have tried till now:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use strict;
use warnings; 
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @elements = split (" ", $line);
    my $row_name = $elements[2];
    print $row_name . "\n";

}
close FILE;
```

How do i make it print the unique values in the same program?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a perl oneliner

```
perl -lane 'print $F[2] if ! $seen{$F[2]}++' file.txt
```

Or within your script, by adding a `%seen` hash as demonstrated in [`perlfaq4 How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my %seen;
while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @elements = split (" ", $line);
    my $row_name = $elements[2];
    print $row_name . "\n" if ! $seen{$row_name}++;
}
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hash to keep track of which values have been seen before.

Also, files named on the command line don't need to be explicitly opened. You can read from them using `<>`, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my %seen;
while (<>) {
  my $col3 = (split)[2];
  print "$col3\n" unless $seen{$col3}++;
}
```

**output**

```
ext3
nfs
ext4
iso9660
```